# Installing Open Suse11.2 on a PC with Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, multi-boot, opensuse-11.2

Currently I have installed in a dual-boot setup, Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Grub2 is the loader.
I want to install openSUSE 11.2 without wrecking havoc on my Windows 7 installation and getting rid of Ubuntu.
How do I get rid of Ubuntu, Grub, **keep Windows7 and install OpenSUSE**.

Will just running OpenSUSE installation, and then deleting the Ubuntu partition be enough? And then won't Grub2 be cluttered with Ubuntu specific entries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the openSUSE installer, during partitioning choose to format the Ubuntu partitions and overwrite them with openSUSE ones. That's all. 
I did the same (albeit, I was using openSUSE 11.2 M8) and it went smooth.

Comment: Thx mate. I'm going to try it during next week.